# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (d is undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-datepicker

I tried previous versions of react datepicker, but it didn't solve.
If it's needed more code here is the repository: https://github.com/RodrigoAN97/revents
Thank you.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useField } from 'formik'
import { FormField, Label } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'

export default function MyDateInput({ label, ...props }){
   const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props)
   return (
      <FormField error={meta.touched && !!meta.error} >
         <label>{label}</label>
         <DatePicker
            {...field}
            {...props}
            selected={(field.value && new Date(field.value)) || null}
            onChange={(e, d) => helpers.setValue(d.value)}
         />
         {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
            <Label basic color='red' > {meta.error} </Label>
         ) : null}
      </FormField>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems your `onChange` callback is wrong, try something like:

```
onChange={e => helpers.setValue(e.target.value)}
```

Answer (score 0):

[There](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) is only one parameter to the `onChange` listener, which is `e`. remove `d`.